# Code repository hosts that support both svn and git?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, repository

Can anyone recommend hosts other than github ( 100% git ), codesion and beanstalk which support both svn and git?

Comment: better fit to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Github supports svn.](http://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support)

Comment: Related long list of repository hosts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111292/free-version-control-services

Answer (score 2):

assembla.com supports both and has some nice other collaboration tools as well.  They offer free repository plans.

Answer (score 0):

you have www.indefero.net. Really like the web interface and has a good support.

Answer (score 0):

[Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) supports both Subversion and Git.

Comment: Hm.. just 10 gb for an enterprise plan!?!?!??!?!?!??!?!?!? Seems low.